# Report builder 3.0 line break in a text string

Tags: sql, report, line, break, builder

I have an SQL table containing text string with remarks added by users every day that are divided by a $ sign (
01.01.2015 remarks 1 $02.01.2015 remarks 2 $03.01.2015 remarks 3 ...). I need to display them in RB so that every new remark starts in a new line. 
I've tried with changing $ in a query with `<br/>` and `vbCrLf` but all I'm getting is continues lines with these constants in the text. They don't want to break. 
Any advice?

Regards,
Timon

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out the following solution on my own; hopefully this will help:

1. Right click on the *expression* (not the cell itself) that you're wanting to contain a text break
2. Click on Expression Properties
3. On the general tab, there are two bubbles under *Markup Type*. You need to select *HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles*
4. Now you can write something like: `="Hello<br> World."` and that should work